# Landsat-5,7 stripe error

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api, cloud-cover

I applied the algorithms to mask cloud in Landsat-5,7 for collection 2, but there are still some stripes in the results. Can anyone help me to figure out this problem?
Here is my code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/b8e35b8000b7e187b6ce89f574f842c8

```
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level0").filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Pakistan'));
Map.addLayer(roi, {color: 'black'}, 'Study Area',1);
Map.centerObject(roi, 6);
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate('2000-6-01', '2000-10-31')
    .filterBounds(roi);

// Applies scaling factors.
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBand, null, true);
}

dataset = dataset.map(applyScaleFactors);

var cloudMaskL5 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  
  // Create bitmasks for cloud, cloud shadow, and bad pixel
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 3;
  var cloudShadowBitMask = 1 << 4;
  var badPixelBitMask = 1 << 0;
  
  // Test if the cloud, cloud shadow, and bad pixel bits are set
  var cloudMask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0);
  var cloudShadowMask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0);
  var badPixelMask = qa.bitwiseAnd(badPixelBitMask).eq(0);
  
  // Combine cloud, cloud shadow, and bad pixel masks
  var combinedMask = cloudMask.and(cloudShadowMask).and(badPixelMask);
  
  // Update the image mask based on the combined mask
  return image.updateMask(combinedMask);
};


// Apply cloud masking function to the ImageCollection
var clouds_free = dataset.map(cloudMaskL5);

// Visualization parameters for the masked true color image (update as needed)
var visualization = {
  bands: ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
};


// Add the cloud-masked true color layer to the map
Map.addLayer(dataset.mean().clip(roi), visualization, 'not cloud mask');

Map.addLayer(clouds_free.mean().clip(roi), visualization, 'cloud mask');
```

[image: stripes]